# What would the unit test look like for a ternary return?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

What would the unit test look like for this component using jest?

```
const SuccessPage = () => {
  const { newFeature } = useSelector(getFeatures);

  return newFeature ? <Component1 /> : <Component2 />;
};

export default SuccessPage;
```

Comment: The same as if you'd have an ordinary `if`. Why would it matter whether there is a conditional operator? As with all unit tests, you do your setup (probably making sure `newFeatures` is `true` or `false`), then call the function, finally check whether the result is what you expect (for `newFeatures = true` check if you get `Component1`). The actual implementation is irrelevant as long as the test checks that the observable behaviour is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You unit tests should test the behavior of the function, not the implementation details. So for this particular function, you should have two tests: one that mocks `useSelector` so that `newFeature` is true and verifies the return value is `<Component1 />`, and another that does the opposite.

You should also have unit test that tests the behavior of `useSelector()`, if that's a function you write yourself.